# gdal_translate 2 bands into JPG RG image

Tags: gdal

I have 2 bands of data (specifically, `u` and `v` wind vectors from GFS in GRIB format) and I'd like to transform it to JPG image into RG channels, B channel empty. How can I use gdal_translate to transform 2 bands? `gdal_translate -scale -128 127 0 255 2020051500.grib 2020051500.jpg` throws "ERROR 6: JPEG driver doesn't support 2 bands.  Must be 1 (grey), 3 (RGB) or 4 bands.".

I can duplicate a band with `gdal_translate -b 1 -b 2 -b 2 -scale -128 127 0 255 2020051500.grib 2020051500.jpg`, but can I avoid it?

Comment: Have you tried building a virtual image with three bands with gdalbuildvrt? This gives you more control about which data goes where, then you can gdal_translate the vrt to jpg

Comment: I don't have the third band, it would need to be created from scratch, with the same dimensions, filled with 0 or nodata. How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my current solution. Scaling the duplicate band to always 0:

`gdal_translate -b 1 -b 2 -b 2 -scale_1 -128 127 0 255 -scale_2 -128 127 0 255 -scale_3 -128 127 0 0 2020051500.grib 2020051500.jpg`

Found at https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/268752/164689